# renaming fasta file using a mapping txt file

Tags: unix, sed, rename, bioinformatics, fasta

Edit solution: https://tejashree1modak.github.io/bioblogs/fasta_rename/

I am looking to rename my scaffolds using a scaffold_mapping.txt file in unix where the .txt file looks like:

```
$ head scaffold_mapping.txt 
>#ID_covAvg_fold_lengthLength
>scaffold_1_c1_cov61.3780_length417825
>scaffold_3_c1_cov45.0025_length77714
>scaffold_4_c1_cov84.2432_length70007
>scaffold_5_c2_cov57.6219_length67890
>scaffold_6_c1_cov331.1665_length65908
>scaffold_7_c1_cov138.5574_length64984
>scaffold_9_c1_cov77.1170_length59223
>scaffold_2_c2_cov51.1554_length55365
>scaffold_11_c1_cov44.1476_length53538
```

Each scaffold in the fasta file is currently named like this:

```
> scaffold_1_c1
```

And I would like their names to match the scaffold_mapping.txt file, so that the previous example would then be:

```
> scaffold_1_c1_cov61.3780_length417825
```

I hoped it'd be easy with sed but the '>' is complicating matters

```
$ sed -f scaffold_mapping1.txt assembly.contigs.fasta > output1.fasta
sed: file scaffold_mapping1.txt line 1: unknown command: `>'
```

Comment: As above from Ed. Please update your question and delete your comment, then we can all delete our comments and save other readers time. Note that cmd file should look more like `s/scaffold_1_c1/scaffold_1_c1_cov61.3780_length417825/` with multiple lines, (I'm not sure what need for your output, so I can't give you exact help. To answer **just** your problem with `>` chars, you can do `sed  's/^> //' file > newFile`. When that is working without errors, you can add `&& mv newFile file` and only have one file. Maybe you can get the `>` fixed at the source? Good luck.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP found an answer on another site.

Comment: ... which uses a CSV of old,new pairs of strings.  Where you *could* use sed to make into `s///` substitutions and then pipe to sed with `sed -f-` to get the script from stdin.   Closest thing to what OP was trying to do.  Make script, pipe to `sed -f- old > new` ... but OP is missing "make script" part.

Comment: @Geomicro ARe you sure there is a blank here: `> scaffold_1_c1`? Fasta files typically have no blanks between `>` and sequence id: `>scaffold_1_c1`

Comment: See also: [replace header in a file (fasta) if match with another file.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437700/replace-header-in-a-file-fasta-if-match-with-another-file-txt)

Answer (score 1):

It's not that "the '>' is complicating matters", you're just telling sed to interpret a file that doesn't contain a sed script.

The question isn't clear but best I can tell this is what the OP wants, using any POSIX awk:

```
awk -F'[> ]+' '
    NR==FNR {
        match($2,/([^_]+_){3}/)
        map[substr($2,1,RLENGTH-1)] = $2
        next
    }
    /^>/ && ($2 in map) {
        $0 = "> " map[$2]
    }
    { print }
' scaffold_mapping.txt the_fasta_file
```

which will output the posted expected output:

```
> scaffold_1_c1_cov61.3780_length417825
```

from the posted sample input.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton for your help.  I didn't articulate myself properly but I found my solution here for anyone reading this thread: https://tejashree1modak.github.io/bioblogs/fasta_rename/

Comment: That's the solution to a problem with simpler input than you said you had so it's doing the same kind of thing as my answer does but without having to deal with parsing the scaffold_mapping.txt format you have.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping file first. Use any scripting language, such as Perl. Then use the mapping file to replace the FASTA headers:

```
tail -n +2 scaffold_mapping.txt | perl -lpe 's{>((scaffold_\d+_c\d+).+)}{${2}\t${1}};' > map.tsv

perl -lpe 'BEGIN { %new = map { chomp; split; } `cat map.tsv`; } s{^>(\S+)}{>$new{$1}}; ' assembly.contigs.fasta > out.fasta
```

Contents of `out.fasta`:

```
>scaffold_1_c1_cov61.3780_length417825
ACTG
>scaffold_1_c1_cov61.3780_length417825
ACTGACTG
>scaffold_4_c1_cov84.2432_length70007
ACTGACTGACTG
231031_1055 m-apd-shtatland test%
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`BEGIN { ... }` : Execute the code before running the rest of the code, here, before parsing the fasta file.
`` %new = map { chomp; split; } `cat map.tsv`; `` : slurp the entire mapping file, store the results in `%new` hash.
`s{^>(\S+)}{>$new{$1}};` : Change the fasta headers (= lines starting with `>` from old to new usage using the `%new` hash. `$1` stores the sequence id, that is whatever was captured inside the parentheses.

**See also:**

- [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)
- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)